# Installation errors when installing executables for EclipseFP

Tags: eclipse, haskell, eclipse-fp

I installed the EclipseFP 2.6.4 plugin under Eclipse Luna, then restarted. When it started to attempt to install the executables for the first time, nothing was installed successfully. I went through all of the log files that were generated and found two that contained errors: ansi-terminal-0.6.2.1 and unix-compat-0.4.1.4.

The log for unix-compat-0.4.1.4:

```
Configuring unix-compat-0.4.1.4...
setup-Cabal-1.18.1.3-x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3.exe: Missing dependency on a
foreign library:
* Missing C library: msvcrt
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

The log for ansi-terminal-0.6.2.1:

```
Configuring ansi-terminal-0.6.2.1...
setup-Cabal-1.18.1.3-x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3.exe: Missing dependency on a
foreign library:
* Missing C library: kernel32
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

I installed the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) 2014.2.0.0 for Windows 64-bit. It is on my path. I read someplace about MinGW being necessary, and MinGW and MSYS are both installed and up-to-date as well and the bin and lib folders for them are on my path. I checked the locations on my path and found a `libmsvctr.a` and `libkernel32.a` in C:\MinGW\mingw32\lib (which is on my path).

I think I'm missing something, but I'm not seeing anything in the [FAQ](http://eclipsefp.github.io/faq.html) or on [the support forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipsefp/discussion/371922).

Comment: In your log a lot of dependent packages have failed to install. For each failure a path to a log file is given. Check these to see what's wrong, maybe just a single dependent package is causing the issue.

Comment: @JPMoresmau I went through all of the logs instead of just a few at random and found two that reported errors. However, I'm not sure how to resolve those errors, especially since the libraries reported as missing are on my path.

Comment: It may be an issue with the PATH when the install is launched from EclipseFP. Try to install buildwrapper and scion-browser from the command line via cabal-install, then you can configure EclipseFP to use the executables you installed. Use a Cabal sandbox to not pollute your system package database.

Comment: `msvcrt` is Microsoft's Visual C runtime library, but i'd think you'd need a `.dll` rather than a `.a`. `kernel32` is also distributed by Microsoft. Are you running 32bit or 64bit? What version of windows?

Comment: @ja. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, 64-bit Eclipse, a 64-bit JDK, 64-bit MinGW, and the 64-bit installer for Haskell Platform. I'll edit this into the question when I'm not on mobile as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why this works. I'm guessing it has to do with dependencies (perhaps down to a version), but the issue was in my PATH environment variables. Haskell Platform comes with MinGW. When I moved Haskell Platform's directories above my MinGW directories in my PATH environment variable, things started to work.

My MinGW is fully installed and up-to-date (at least as far as I can tell), so it may be the Haskell Platform has a dependency that's not a standard part of MinGW or has a dependency on specific versions of tools. Either way, moving the Haskell Platform directories (including the MinGW that comes with Haskell Platform) up first in my PATH variables resolved the issues.